# How to Upload a Single Object to a Transfer Acceleration Enabled Bucket by Android SDK

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, transfer, acceleration

I use [Android SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid) to upload files to AWS S3, and want enable transfer accelerate.
I have read [transfer acceleration examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration-examples.html) but only found example for Java. I tried the Java code on Android  but with no success:

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, clientConfiguration);
S3ClientOptions s3ClientOptions = new S3ClientOptions();
s3ClientOptions.setAccelerateModeEnabled(true);
s3Client.setS3ClientOptions(s3ClientOptions);
```

Cannot resolve method 'setAccelerateModeEnabled'! The version of my aws-android-sdk-s3 is 2.2.16.

Is Transfer Acceleration supported on Android SDK? If yes, how should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Mobile SDK for Android v2.2.17 is released today. This release adds support for Amazon S3 transfer acceleration, cross-region replication and list objects v2. For more information, see http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/5606404750751710.

The above code will work after you upgrade the SDK to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.

Comment: Yes, I updated the SDK version and can enable transfer acceleration now. With a little change for my code: using S3ClientOptions.Builder to setAccelerateModeEnabled

Comment: I have a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477638/aws-s3-returnedmetadata-getetag-return-null, Can you help to take a look at it please, thank you.