# AWS S3 returnedMetadata getETag return null

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use [AWS Android SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid) to upload files by cellular networks, but failed with the following exception stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
        at com.amazonaws.util.BinaryUtils.fromHex(BinaryUtils.java:59)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1724)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.uploadSinglePartAndWaitForCompletion(UploadTask.java:203)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:85)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:44)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

the line which threw the exception is:

```
byte[] serverSideHash = BinaryUtils.fromHex(returnedMetadata.getETag());
```

The returnedMetadata is:

```
 0 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@23771} "X-Amz-Request-Id" -> "DEE81C23A4C3CC36"
 1 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@23772} "X-Android-Sent-Millis" -> "1469025911653"
 2 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@23773} "Content-Length" -> "0"
 3 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@23774} "X-Amz-Id-2" -> "VmX88R/qlpZakm+2V0hmsSqUVRsE6Bk/ReytA2+aNsmlzGvyzRoxlt9eTTn7nNpUrvHwlSXf+0U="
 4 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@23775} "Etag" -> ""40193f75932daad6cc8bfd123538b255""
 5 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@23776} "X-Android-Response-Source" -> "NETWORK 200"
 6 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@23777} "X-Android-Received-Millis" -> "1469025921747"
```

and in com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata.java:

```
public String getETag() {
    return (String) metadata.get(Headers.ETAG);
}
```

and in com.amazonaws.services.s3.Headers:

```
public static final String ETAG = "ETag";
```

You see? The constant String defined in Headers is "ETag" with uppercase 'T' while the one in the returnedMetadata is lowercase! That's why returnedMetadata.getETag() return null!

I also tried some other phone which can upload files successfully. And the returnedMetadata looks like:

```
0 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@13854} "X-Android-Sent-Millis" -> "1469003845678"
1 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@13855} "Content-Length" -> "0"
2 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@13856} "ETag" -> "80db7338d4d25c1fc01ccf0a005f6127"
3 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@13857} "X-Android-Response-Source" -> "NETWORK 200"
4 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@13858} "X-Android-Received-Millis" -> "1469003848950"
```

So my questions are:

1.Why some returnedMetadata is "Etag" and the other is "ETag"

2.Is the value for `{HashMap$HashMapEntry@23775} "Etag" -> ""40193f75932daad6cc8bfd123538b255""` correct? Note: the value with **DOUBLE quotation marks.**

Note：This problem occurred when I use cellular networks.

My AWS SDK version is **2.2.20**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: That's interesting. Not sure if the ISP would change headers. How do you reproduce the problem? What's the make/model of your device?

Comment: My device name: Galaxy S6 edge, model: SM-G9250, Android version 5.1.1,

Comment: So, only this device on cellular has issue? Does it have issue on Wifi? Do other devices on cellular have the same issue?

Comment: wifi is ok. Currently tested for 4 phones using cellular only one phone has the issue.

Comment: I don't think it's caused by the SDK. This header is probably changed by the device or ISP. I suggest you write some code to see if whether the header is modified by the device/iSP. One idea is to hit http://sdk-for-android.amazonwebservices.com/latest/aws-android-sdk.zip or any other site that will return ETag header with HttpURLConnection. In theory, you would get ETag header in the correct case.